# How to remove the legend from geom_point and move the linetype legend of two smooth lines to the inside of the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe `df`:

```
df<- data.frame(C.D=c(5,5,5,10,10,10,20,20,20,40,40,40,80,80,80,100,100,100,130,130,130,160,160,160,190,190,190,220,220,220,250,250,250,280,280,280,310,310,310,340,340,340,359,359,359),
                Activity=c(1.1,1.6,0.6,1.2,1.8,1.3,1.3,1.4,1.88,0.99,1.8,2.1,1.75,1.5,2.4,1.55,0.9,2.4,1.4,1.5,3.2,1.7,2.1,3.8,2.8,3.9,2.1,3.4,2.6,4.1,2.3,3.6,4.3,3.0,2.4,1.8,2.5,1.6,1.1,0.5,1.4,2.3,0.8,2.1,1.5),
                C.I=c(0.05,0.21,0.11,0.2,0.15,0.28,0.24,0.18,0.33,0.11,0.22,0.13,0.16,0.31,0.23,0.15,0.28,0.36,0.25,0.31,0.58,0.42,0.36,0.52,0.58,0.82,0.71,0.64,0.51,0.4,0.54,0.55,0.68,0.32,0.21,0.23,0.37,0.22,0.15,0.21,0.24,0.18,0.04,0.6,0.12))

df

   C.D Activity  C.I
1    5     1.10 0.05
2    5     1.60 0.21
3    5     0.60 0.11
4   10     1.20 0.20
.    .       .    .
.    .       .    .
.    .       .    .
```

I also have the code showed below to create a plot from the dataframe `df`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(C.D, Activity)) +
  geom_point(aes(C.D, Activity, color = C.I)) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("green","black")) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = "Activity"))  +
  ggtitle("Activity ~ Current Direction 20 meters") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(C.D, C.I * 6, linetype = "C.I."), se=FALSE, colour = "red", show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . / 6, name = "CI")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values = c(1,1), 
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = c("blue", "red")))
  )
```

[image]

However, I want to arrange several plots together with `grid.arrange` (4x4) and I need to remove all the legends from the right side. I want to delete the legend relative to the code line `geom_point(aes(C.D.4m, VeDBA, color = C.I.4m))` and move the legend about the `linetype` to the insede of the graph (middle-upper side).

If I try `theme(legend.position='none')` I remove both legends. How could I do to delete the legend relative to how I colour in `geom_point` and to move the legend relative to the `linetype` to the inside of the plot?

Comment: Hi Dekike, I edit my post to make the plot keep your color scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `guide = FALSE` in `scale_colour_continous` to get rid of the color legend and then use `legend.justification` and `legend.position` to move the linetype legend.

So, for your plot, you should do the following:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(C.D, Activity)) +
  geom_point(aes(C.D, Activity, color = C.I)) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("green","black")) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = "Activity"))  +
  ggtitle("Mean activity as a function of C.D.20m for winter from hourly data") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(C.D, C.I * 6, linetype = "C.I."), se=FALSE, colour = "red", show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . / 6, name = "CI")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values = c(1,1), 
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = c("blue", "red")))
  ) + 
  scale_colour_continuous(guide = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.justification = c(1,1),
        legend.position = c(1,1))
```

And get the following plot:

[image]

**EDIT**

I just realized that this solution was not keeping the color schme (green dot). An another solution is to use `show.legend = FALSE` in the `geom_point`. 
So, if you are doing that:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(C.D, Activity)) +
  geom_point(aes(C.D, Activity, color = C.I),show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("green","black")) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = "Activity"))  +
  ggtitle("Mean activity as a function of C.D.20m for winter from hourly data") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(C.D, C.I * 6, linetype = "C.I."), se=FALSE, colour = "red", show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . / 6, name = "CI")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values = c(1,1), 
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = c("blue", "red")))
  )  +
  theme(legend.justification = c(1,1),
        legend.position = c(1,1))
```

You're getting the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Great!!! I was just writing you this .... I was going to ask you how to maintain the colour of the points... Your answer now is perfect. Thank you very much :)

Comment: My pleasure ! That's the issue when you're working on a small screen, sometimes you see plot changes only after posting ... my bad.